# Loop through all sheets, if cell=string, copy three cells to special sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm working with excel 2007. I have an invoice system where I type in a purchase order number and it generates a new invoice with that p.o. number as the sheet name and also copies it to a cell on the same sheet, then from there it is manually filled out and saved. Each invoice has one of fourteen supply types (for example, Printing Supplies or Cleaning Supplies chosen from a dropdown list) in cell C6. That all works great.
I want to keep track of how much is spent on each supply type, so I need to go through every invoice, check for supply type and copy three non-contiguous cells (date (A6:B6), po# (F6:G6) and amount (G39)) to a row in the "checkbook style" sheet for that supply type.

I guess the pseudo code would look like this:

- For each sheet, check for supply type in cell c6
- If supply type is printing,
- write the three cell values in a new row to the sheet called Printing, otherwise go on to next
- if the supply type is cleaning,
- write the three cell values in a new row to the sheet called Cleaning
- and so forth, "if"ing myself to death.

Here is what I have that simply went through all sheets and copied the cells without sorting them by supply type - then I tried to get it to use just the Printing invoices with no success.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromPrintingWorksheets()


Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
'Delete the sheet "Printing" if it exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Printing").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet with the name
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Printing"

'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
    If InStr(1, Worksheets(wks.Name).Range("C6:E6").Value, "Printing/Stationary 532-110", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
    ' If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 4)) = "tly-" Then

        'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)

        'Fill in the range that you want to copy
        Set CopyRng = sh.Range("G3")


        'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
        If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
            GoTo ExitTheSub
        End If

        'This copies values/formats, want to copy the
        'values or want to copy everything
        CopyRng.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "B")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the A column
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name
        'Copy ordered by cell to column C
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "D").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Range("G39")
        'Copy date cell to proper column
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "C").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Range("C6")
        DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "E").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Range("E8")
    End If
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

I even researched select case, but still have had no success.  Tried recording a marco and looking at that code with no inspiration. This seems like it shouldn't be that difficult...but I don't know the most practical way to go about it. A pointer in the right direction would be fantastic!

Comment: The ``Instr`` line of code has several issues. 1) ``wks`` is not declared or set.  2) The ``.Value`` property returns an array when the ``Range`` object is more than one cell; this will not work inside the ``Instr`` function.

Comment: Why are coding this yourself?  I do not know where you are located but your lake looks too blue for England.  Here you can buy a suite of entry level financial modules (Invoicing Module, Sales Ledger,  Purchase Ledger, Nominal Ledger, Limited Stock Control, VAT Module (with Online Submissions), New Chase Debt Function, Outlook Diary Integration, Improved Financial Reporting and Excel Integrated Reporting) for less than £350.

Comment: Tony - because to people that only punch in the numbers, it sounds very easy, and they happen to be the ones in charge. :)

Comment: Laura - I too have had bosses with no comprehension of how long it takes to create a complete, useable purchaser order system.  Unless (even if!) you are paid peanuts, this is going to be a very, very expensive system.  Does it have to be Excel?  Can you follow Phoog's advice and use Access?  I can suggest easier ways of doing this in Excel if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving this in VBA is possible, but it's going to be fairly cumbersome and brittle.

One problem with this approach is that you have data stored in multiple places that could get out of sync.  Also, you want three different views of your data:

- single-record view (i.e., a single purchase order)
- multiple-record view (i.e., "checkbook style"), possibly grouped or filtered by supply type
- summary view (totals for a given date range and/or supply type)

This is fairly trivial to do in Access or a more serious database system, but a little searching leads me to believe that in Excel you can get two of the above but not all three.  Nonetheless, the below links may help somewhat:

You can use a 3-d reference to sum data, but I don't think you can create a pivot table from a 3-d reference (for a checkbook-style view):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx

You can also consolidate multiple worksheets into a pivot table, but it looks like the source data must already be in checkbook-style view, so there's no way to get a single-invoice view of the data:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-report-HA010226585.aspx

---

Bottom line: If you have some time to devote to this, I'd recommend moving the solution to Access.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  I have upvoted your answer because you get to the key point that this is not an Excel application more quickly.

Comment: phoog - Absolutely what I needed to hear. Given that the time frame for this project was particularly short, and in addition to my other duties, I respectfully declined and insisted that it be done right or get someone else to do it.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I came to the same conclusion as phoog but in a different direction.  Below I work through your code suggesting changes but I find it difficult to believe you could make this work.

**Point 1**

Do you have multiple workbooks open?  Do you switch between them before running your macro?  Suppose you have three workbooks (A, B and C) open.  Suppose, also, this macro and the invoices are in workbook A.  If you using workbook C when you start the macro, C will be ActiveWorkBook.  It is possible to run macros across multiple workbooks but it adds a level of complication I believe you can do without.  If you only have one workbook open when you start the macro, you do not need `ActiveWorkbook.`.

**Point 2**

I do not like using `On Error` for errors I can avoid.  It is probably not important but deleting something and then recreating it feels wrong to me.  I would do it like this:

```
Dim DestSh as Worksheet
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim InxWS As Integer

Found = False
For InxWS = 1 To Worksheets.Count
  If Worksheets(InxWS).Name = "Printing" Then
    Found = True
    ' Use whichever of the following two statements is most appropriate
    ' This completely deletes the contents of the worksheet
    Worksheets(InxWS).Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    ' This deletes the contents of the worksheet but keeps the column widths
    Worksheets(InxWS).Cells.EntireRow.ClearContents
    Exit For
  End If
Next
If Not Found Then
  Set DestSh = Worksheets.Add
  DestSh.Name = "Printing"
End If
```

**Point 3**

I see nothing wrong with the following:

```
For Each sh In Worksheets
  If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then 


  End If
Next
```

`For Each` is a perfectly good way of working through the worksheets.

You need some method of checking you are not examining worksheet "Printing".  However, if the destination worksheet is always going to be "Printing" I might write `sh.Name <> "Printing"`.

On the other hand, if I wanted to show off, I would write:

```
Const DestShName as String = "Printing"
 :      :
DestSh.Name = DestShName
 :      :
If sh.Name <> DestShName Then
```

With this code, I could change the name of the destination sheet by changing the Const (constant) statement.

**Point 4**

Consider:

```
Worksheets(wks.Name).Range("C6:E6").Value
```

What is `wks`?  The for variable is `sh`?

I would guess you do not have `Option Explicit` as the first line of your module.  `Option Explicit` says you want to be forbidden from using undeclared variables.

`Worksheets(sh.Name)` is the same as `sh`.

I assume "C6:E6" have been merged.  If you want the value of a merged area, use the top left cell.  So `Range("C6").Value`.

Your Select Case will be on the form:

```
With sh
  Select Case .Range("C6").Value
    Case "Printing"
      ' Do something
    Case "Cleaning"
      ' Do something
    Case "Stationary"
      ' Do something
    Case "Books"
      :     :
    Case Else
      ' Do something about an unknown supply type
  End Select
End With
```

**Point 5**

If I have understood correctly, you have 14 supply types each with its own destination sheet.  You are going to need a `Select Case` like this in the loop to prepare the destination sheets.  Is the supply type the same as the worksheet name?  If not, this is going to get very messy particularly if you add another supply type.

It may be worth thinking about arrays.

```
Dim InxShST as Integer 
Dim SheetNameList() as String
Dim SupplyTypeList() as String

SheetNameList = Array("Print", "Clean", "Stat", ... )
SupplyTypeList = Array("Printing supplies", "Cleaning supplies", ... )
```

With the sheet names and supply types in the same sequence you can find a supply type in a purchase order and convert it to a sheet name.  If you add a new supply type, just add a new value to the end of each array.

Return to point 2.  I suggest you forget about adding worksheets by VBA; create the 14 sheets by hand.

The code becomes:

```
For InxWS = 1 To Worksheets.Count
  For InxShST = LBound(SheetNameList) To UBound(SheetNameList)
    If Worksheets(InxWS).Name = SheetNameList(InxShST) Then
      Worksheets(InxWS).Cells.EntireRow.ClearContents
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
Next
```

I admit this is more complicated but it prepares as many sheets as you need.  You have two loops: one for the worksheets and one for the worksheet names.  When you get a match, you have a sheet that needs clearing.  `LBound` stands for Lower Bound.  `UBound` stands for Upper Bound.  The second `For-Loop` adjusts to the size of the array.

You could use:

```
  For Each SheetNameCrnt In SheetNameList
```

This may look simpler.  But by using an index you can relate `SheetNameList(InxShST)` to `SupplyTypeList(InxShST)`

**Other points**

Are you sure you want one worksheet per purchase order?  How many purchase orders do you have a day.  10? 100? 500?  This could be a very unmanageable workbook.

From the other statements in your macro, I assume you have a fixed header and then one data row per product ordered.  You do not define the nature of these rows but I guess you want to copy them to the appropriate worksheet.

I could perhaps guess the structure of these data rows but I must question your design.  If I order a printer cartridge and some soap powder from you, do I need two purchase orders?  I do not think you will win my business.

Comment: +1 for a very thorough and thoroughly excellent answer.  If I could upvote more than once, I would.

Comment: Yeah, the Instr line was from somewhere else, sorry.  Thank you for your expertise, it definitely helped me.